# Understanding Rails 6 JavaScript directories

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby on Rails so I wanted to understand how the JavaScript directories are managed in a Rails application!

> **1. What is the difference between the three directories:**
>
> - `project-name/app/assets/config` : contains JS files:
> - `project-name/app/javascripts/channels` : contains JS files:
> - `project-name/app/javascripts/packs` : contains JS files

In my case these files have the following contents:

```
project-name/app/assets/config/manifest.js:
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
project-name/app/javascripts/channels/consumer.js:
// Action Cable provides the framework to deal with WebSockets in Rails.
// You can generate new channels where WebSocket features live using the `bin/rails generate channel` command.

import { createConsumer } from "@rails/actioncable"

export default createConsumer()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
project-name/app/javascripts/channels/index.js:
// Load all the channels within this directory and all subdirectories.
// Channel files must be named *_channel.js.

const channels = require.context('.', true, /_channel\.js$/)
channels.keys().forEach(channels)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
project-name/app/javascripts/packs/application.js:
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

---

What I basically want to do is execute is execute ruby code with `sweetalert2` JavaScript. But I found out that this is impossible to do (see my other question: [How to execute a rails command with sweet alert 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67433768/how-to-execute-a-rails-command-with-sweet-alert-2))

I found out that referencing JavaScript files using cdn (e.g.`<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>`) is not of common use, and that Rails prefer using gems (e.g. `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>`). So that lead to the following questions:

After installing a gem (add `gem 'jquery-rails'` in Gemsfile and then `bundle` on terminal), most tutorials will add the `//= require jquery` in `project-name/app/assets/javascripts/application.js` but I don't have that file!

> 2. Where do I have to provide `//= require <gem-name>` from the above directories?

> 3. Where do I want to add my custom JavaScript files (for the moment I'm using the following directory: `project-name/app/views/friends/javascripts/<my-JS-Files>`) but I know that's wrong!

Comment: You don't use `//= require <gem-name>` with webpacker. Thats a directive for spockets - the old assets pipeline. It does nothing in webpacker just like any other comment. In Webpacker in general you don't use "gemmified" assets. Instead you install packages through Yarn.